# Concatenating Bootstrap, jQuery and local JavaScript - breaks jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, minify

Currently I minify and concatenate my JavaScript and CSS files for my local 'theme'. Then I load the Bootstrap, jQuery and my local JavaScript/css files in the head of my website.

Whilst this works, it does result in 8 separate resource loads, rather than just 2 (1 for JS, 1 for CSS) which is what I would like to accomplish. (At this time I am not looking to asynchronously load multiple libraries).

I'm using Grunt in my build system in order to invoke the Uglify action to minifiy my JavaScript.

Below is the relevant part of my Gruntfile.js

```
uglify: {
    build: {
        files: [{
            src: ['src/main/webapp/js/vendor/*.js', 'src/main/webapp/js/*.js', '!src/main/webapp/js/output.min.js'],
            dest: 'src/main/webapp/js/output.min.js'
        }]
    }
}
```

I thought that by specifying the already minified jQuery and Bootstrap libraries to the Uglify action I could get it to combine the libraries with my minified 'theme' JavaScript. However when doing so, I then receive the following errors in my browser:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Obviously by concatenating and minifying these files I'm breaking something.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've tried using the minified and unminified versions of the Bootstrap and jQuery libraries just to be sure.

Cheers,
Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you include bootstrap's javascript files before jQuery.

Bootstrap is jQuery dependent. You need to include jQuery first and then anything that needs jQuery.

Comment: Ha, now I feel like a muppet... By doing /vendor/*.js it was obviously iterating over the files in alphabetical order - doing Bootstrap before jQuery. I've now explicitly set each file in order and it works perfectly. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using the standard `grunt-contrib-concat` for the concatenation, you need to ensure that you specify the files in the correct order.

For example, in my work Grunt config file (I work with Foundation rather than Bootstrap, but they are both dependent on jQuery) I have the following settings for my vendor/external files. `build/external.all.min.js` is the pre-minified code built up from jQuery first, then foundation, and then all the other scripts.

```
files: {
  'build/external-all.min.js': [
  'build/external/jquery.min.js',
  'build/external/foundation.min.js',
  'build/external/*.js']
}
```

Comment: I went through this recently. If you want to use Grunt to concat your scripts, you'll have to assure proper file sequence manually at least for those than have dependencies. Same with some style sheets, if you depend on them cascading correctly and don't use @imports.

Comment: Hi thanks for this - it turns out it was an issue with the ordering that I hadn't picked up on. I've marked @Ivanka Tordorova's answer as correct simply because it came in first. Thanks for your help!